# Pig - Is there a better way to format a value with 6 digits

Tags: apache-pig

I am developing a pig script and have to display the number as 6 digits eventhough the number is 4 digit.

```
ex: 6001 should be displayed as 006001.
```

Thank you.

Comment: SPRINTF https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/SPRINTF.html

Comment: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.builtin.SPRINTF using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: y = foreach x generate org.apache.pig.builtin.SPRINTF('%04d',val1);

Comment: using Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.8.3

Comment: Thanks. This function is added only in 0.14.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can cast it to string and append '00'.

```
y = foreach x generate CONCAT('00',(chararray)val1);
```